# R creating dataframe

Tags: r

I have a sequence:

```
seq <- seq (5, 10)
```

and list of floats like:

```
values<-runif(20,0,15)
> values
 [1]  3.9826299  5.5818585  8.5928005 13.6231168  3.0252290 13.4758453
 [7] 14.1701290  9.9119669  9.4367107  0.9267941  3.0896186  2.6483513
[13] 10.3053427  5.7615558 11.5476213  7.4654886 10.7642776 14.8785914
[19]  5.7005277 11.6616783
```

I need to create dataframe, which 1st column will contain `sequence`, and second - count of numbers from the `values`, which is greater than sequence number.
like

```
    seq sum
1   5  15
2   6  12
3   7  12
4   8  11
5   9  10
6  10   8
```

Comment: Please show a small example and expected output based on that example

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour] and specially reading [ask]

Comment: List: 0.0159, 0.02, 0.3, 1.2, 3.2
Sequence : 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4
Result will be dataframe like:

0 - 5;
0.1 - 3;
0.2 - 3;
0.3 - 2;
0.4 - 2;

Comment: It would be better to update your post.

Comment: Just in case you missed it: there's and [edit] button just under your question.

Comment: sorry for my shitty explanation, i will work on it

Comment: @Igor feel free to ping with @ name once done so we can reopen the question

Comment: Jus move your comment to your question. That's it.

Comment: fixed question, sorry, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this:

```
> set.seed(1)
> seq<-5:10
> values<-runif(20,0,15)
> values
 [1]  3.9826299  5.5818585  8.5928005 13.6231168  3.0252290 13.4758453
 [7] 14.1701290  9.9119669  9.4367107  0.9267941  3.0896186  2.6483513
[13] 10.3053427  5.7615558 11.5476213  7.4654886 10.7642776 14.8785914
[19]  5.7005277 11.6616783
> data.frame(seq,sum=sapply(seq,function(x)sum(values[values>x])))
  seq      sum
1   5 152.8775
2   6 135.8336
3   7 135.8336
4   8 128.3681
5   9 119.7753
6  10 100.4266
```

Edit: from your comment, it looks like you actually want this:

```
> data.frame(seq,sum=sapply(seq,function(x)sum(values>x)))
  seq sum
1   5  15
2   6  12
3   7  12
4   8  11
5   9  10
6  10   8
```

Comment: i just need to count them, but that's help, thank you

Comment: thank you sooo much, i cant get this for couple hours!

Comment: You could probably both make it cleaner and speed it up using `colSums(sapply(seq, "<", values))`